# CSS Relative Positioning and Vertical Alignment with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to convert a image mockup into HTML/CSS and I'm struggling to get things positioning correctly - in particular with vertical alignment, and with getting things to stay in relative position as you resize the window.

JSFiddle code:

http://jsfiddle.net/victorhooi/ZcrCc/

Full-screen JSFiddle output:

http://jsfiddle.net/victorhooi/ZcrCc/embedded/result/

I have this mockup:

[image]

But if you look at the JSFiddle above, I can't seem to get the opening and closing branches, along with the type images in the centre to be vertically aligned within the white box - they're everywhere.

The HTML:

```
<section id="proposal" class="backgroundphotos">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 panel panel-default">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2">
                    <img src="http://www.victorandalpha.com/images/curly_brackets_open.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img src="http://www.victorandalpha.com/images/proposal_01.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.victorandalpha.com/images/proposal_02.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.victorandalpha.com/images/proposal_03.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img src="http://www.victorandalpha.com/images/proposal_04.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.victorandalpha.com/images/proposal_05.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.victorandalpha.com/images/proposal_06.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img src="http://www.victorandalpha.com/images/proposal_07.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.victorandalpha.com/images/proposal_08.png" />
                    <img src="http://www.victorandalpha.com/images/proposal_09.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <img src="http://www.victorandalpha.com/images/curly_brackets_close.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

with the CSS:

```
    .backgroundphotos {
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: scroll; /* Why does this not carry over? */
        min-height: 800px;

    }

    #proposal {
        background: url(../img/04.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }

    #proposal > div.row > div > div.row > div {
        position: relative;
        bottom: -90px;
    }

    #proposal > div.row {
        position: relative;
        bottom: -22.500em;
    }
```

*NB: I've edited the original question to split it into separate ones for the other CSS positioning issues. The related questions are here:*

[CSS Positioning two elements relative to each other, and keeping there during resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101932/css-positioning-two-elements-relative-to-each-other-and-keeping-during-resize)

[CSS Positioning for Glyphicon-based Navbar that Opens on Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102042/css-positioning-for-glyphicon-based-navbar-that-opens-on-hover)

Comment: Have you tried simply adding `min-width` attributes to the `div`s to keep them from overlapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will edit my answer when I have more time to check the other issues (you might want to consider making them separate questions) but for your first issue regarding the branches you shouldn't use `bottom: -90px`

```
    #proposal > div.row > div > div.row > div {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0px; //changed from -90 to just 0
    }
```

The branches were formatted perfectly but by doing this you made them shift down.

The problem then though is the picture is aligned correctly. I added `bottom: -40px` to the class `.col-md-offset-2` but that's bootstrap stuff so you probably don't want to edit that. Maybe make your own class so you can just directly add it or encapsulate all the `.col-md-offset-2` divs in a wrapper div that you can shift downward.

Comment: I've edited the JSFiddle code to position the branches and the typography separately http://jsfiddle.net/victorhooi/ZcrCc/4/ and http://jsfiddle.net/victorhooi/ZcrCc/4/embedded/result/ - however, it still doesn't deal well with resizing - the typography parts just end up overlapping each other.

Comment: yikes... I see what you're saying. If you want it to resize... it might be easier to just make that into its own image and then set it as a background-image. That way when you resize it, it will shrink it appropriately.